# How to run a query only when another has completed with express js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

Please take it gentle on me i am new to node js. I am running two queries in a for loop that will insert values into two tables named orders and requests. after the insertion into the orders table i take the insertId and pass it to the variable orderid and then add that for my second insertion query. All that works fine and when its done i want to query a view named invoice so that i can get some of the information i just put into the database. The issue is it returns the results from the view even before the two queries are done hence i get an empty response. This is my code .

```
for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
  connection.query('INSERT INTO orders(referenceid,itemid,quantity,dac,requestid,locationid) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);',[referenceid,items[i].id,items[i].quantity,dac,requestid,locationid], function(errors,results,fields){
                if(errors){ throw errors};
                    var orderid = results.insertId;
                connection.query('INSERT INTO requests(requestid,orderid,price) VALUES(?,?,?)',[requestid,orderid,price],function(errors,results,fields){
                })
  })

}
connection.query('SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE requestid = ? ,[requestid],function(errors,results,fields){
                })
```

so can anyone help me with a way to let the SELECT query run only when all the insertions in the for loop are done. My database is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which SQL npm module you're using so I can't reference any documentation but I believe what's going on is that you're calls to `connection.query()` are asynchronous, as they should be. This results in your final `connection.query()` outside the for loop to be executed before the ones inside the for loop, hence, you'll have no `requestId` to use in your final query.

Two possible solutions I can provide off the bat include:

- Nest your query calls into the callbacks
- Use explicit promises

So for the first option, you can just put the final query into the nested callback of your query into the `requests` table. From my understanding, you only wish to select rows from `invoice` once your inserts into `orders` & `requests` are complete.

As for the second option, you can refactor the contents of your for loop into a helper function and encapsulate it with `return new Promise()` so something like this:

```
const helper = (<any_params_you_need>) => {
   return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
      for(var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
         connection.query('INSERT INTO orders(referenceid,itemid,quantity,dac,requestid,locationid) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);',[referenceid,items[i].id,items[i].quantity,dac,requestid,locationid], function(errors,results,fields){
                if(errors) { reject(err); }
                var orderid = results.insertId;
                connection.query('INSERT INTO requests(requestid,orderid,price) 
                VALUES(?,?,?)', 
                [requestid,orderid,price],function(errors,results,fields){
                    resolve(results);
                })
         })
      }
   }
}
```

And once you set up the helper function you can just call it with an `await` like so: `await helper();` before your select query. For instance, in the calling function it would look something like:

```
...
const results = await helper();
connection.query('SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE requestid = ? ,[requestid],function(errors,results,fields){});
...
```

Comment: I can't use the nested call backs because it is a for loop and hence it will call for the view every time the for loop is run but i want it to only run when the for loop is done. For your second solution i am still new to node so if you could write it using my code i would be very grateful. Because i don't know if the for loop is supposed to go into the new promise or if the final query to the invoice view is supposed to be in there. so if you could write it using my code.

Comment: Oh then the second solution is probably the one to go with. I have updated the answer with some of your existing code b/c it would be too long to put in a comment. Please note that inside a promise, you can `resolve` the promise with any value that you want returned from the promise. For more about promises you can check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise